# Returning Laravel DB::table('...')->get() as a Collection of Model instead of StdClass

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

The `DB::table('my_table')->get()` returns a Collection of `StdClass`.

Is it possible to return a collection of `MyTable`, instead of `StdClass`? Is there a "laravel way" of doing this?

To ilustrate my problem, I have this query on my model `Item`:

```
        return DB::table('attribute_values')
          ->join('items_categories', 'attribute_values.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.id')
          ->where('items_categories.item_id', '=', $this->id)
          ->select('attribute_values.*')
          ->get();
```

and I need the collection of model `AttributeValue`. Currently I'm iterating through the collection of `stdClass` and instantiating the AttributeValue's.

Comment: You could use `Eloquent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create modes based on `attrubute_values` and their relationships e.g.

```
class ItemCatogory extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
      protected $table = "item_categories";

      public attributeValues() {
          return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
      }
}

class AttributeValue extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model { 
     public itemCategories() {
          return $this->belongsTo(ItemCategory::class);
     } 
}
```

Then you can query for this model:

```
 return AttributeValues::with("itemCategories")->get(); //eager loading of relationship
```

You can also lazy load the relationships:

```
$attrValue = AttributeValues->first(); //Relationship not loaded
$categories = $attrValue->itemCategories()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos! I didin't mentioned but the `ItemCatogory` is a `Pivot` class. I know that in some cases I can define Eloquent relationships, like you did, but in this case I need to execute some queries and grab the results as model objects, not stdClass.

Comment: This should still work in this case, but I don't think you can consider the `item_category` table to be a pivot table to the m-n relationship between `item` and `category` (I'm assuming) when it has relationships itself. You should think of an itemcategory as its own entity.

Comment: You're entirely right. My mistake was using the `item_category` as a Pivot instead of a Model. Thank you very much for open my mind to this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is so obvious, but if it helps someone, here is how I was doing:

```
//it returns a Collection of StdClass
return DB::table('attribute_values')
  ->join('items_categories', 'attribute_values.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.id')
  ->where('items_categories.item_id', '=', $this->id)
  ->select('attribute_values.*')
  ->get();
```

And how must be to return a collection of Eloquent Models:

```
//it returns a Collection of AttributeValue (my model class)
return AttributeValue::join('items_categories', 'attribute_values.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.id')
  ->where('items_categories.item_id', '=', $this->id)
  ->get();
```